# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSServiceBuilderExtension

Tags: apache-axis

Exception appeared.
But class path and maven version are fine.
And tried maven clean build also..

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSServiceBuilderExtension
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_281]